# how to implement gradle system test that get executed after a jenkins deployment?

Tags: jenkins, testing, gradle, deployment, system

I have a gradle project that is built by Jenkins within the following steps:

1. Build the project, run unit- and integrationtests
2. Build and publish docker images
3. Deploy application to pre-production
4. *Run system tests on pre-production*
5. Deploy application to production

Now step 4 is not ready yet and I am wondering about how to implement this in the most convenient way..?

I want to use JUnit5 and the tests should be inside the project itself, so either in one of the modules or with a separate module that is also included and has some other modules as dependencies.

When I create a separate module with normal JUnit5 tests for it, these Tests get automatically executed in Step 1. So what I want to achieve is a custom gradle step for these system tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to do so would be to implement a new gradle task and a new source set with the same name - for example "systemTest". Here is the sample code for a multi module gradle project that has a simple system test:

**my file hierarchy:**

```
├── application
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   └── java
│       │       └── de
│       │           └── mycompany
│       │               └── mydepartment
│       │                   └── projectname
│       │                       └── Application.java
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── de
│                   └── mycompany
│                       └── mydepartment
│                           └── projectname
│                               └── ApplicationTest.java
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── Jenkinsfile
├── settings.gradle
└── systemtests
    ├── build.gradle
    └── src
        └── systemTest
            └── java
                └── de
                    └── mycompany
                        └── mydepartment
                            └── projectname
                                └── SystemTest.java
```

**Application.java** contains my business logic (that should shomehow deploy an application to docker or whatever).

**ApplicationTest.java** is a JUnit5 unit test that will be run during the build process.

**SystemTest.java** is a JUnit5 test that is intended to be run after a deployment. We can do this (manually or automatically if the command is added into a build script) via `./gradlew systemTest`.

Now let's look at the gradle files:

**build.gradle** (root):

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'Nexus-Internal Access'
            url 'http://m2repo.system.local/content/groups/full/'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.6.0'
        testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: '5.6.0'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java { output.resourcesDir = outputDir }
        }
        test {
            java { output.resourcesDir = outputDir }
        }
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

**settings.gradle** (root):

```
rootProject.name = 'service'

include 'application'
include 'systemtests'
```

**application/build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'application'

application {
    mainClassName = 'de.mycompany.mydepartment.projectname.Application'
}
```

**systemtests/build.gradle**:

```
configurations {
    systemTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
}

sourceSets {
    systemTest {
        java { output.resourcesDir = outputDir }
    }

    jar.duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}

task systemTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    group = 'verification'
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.systemTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.systemTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

**Jenkinsfile** (untested phrases for your inspiration):

```
#!groovy

node {
    stage("Build") {
        sh """
            ./gradlew clean build
        """
    }
    stage("Build docker containers") {
        sh """
            docker build application
        """
    }
    stage("Deploy to pre-prod") {
        sh """
            oc rollout application to testserver
        """
    }
    stage("System Tests") {
        sh """
            ./gradlew clean systemTest --info
        """
    }
    stage("Deploy to prod") {
        sh """
            oc rollout application to prod
        """
    }
}
```

Note that I use `--info` on the `/gradlew systemTest` task so that I can read logs coming from the system test in the Jenkins Console. I am also using system properties to pass some credentials from our Jenkins into gradle. with another `-Pname=${var}` parameter for the systemTest task. Omitted here so that nobody gets confused :)